# Empty disk partition after opening Windows 8

Tags: 12.10, windows-8, disk

I have both Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 on my machine. I always use Ubuntu and nearly never logged in to Windows 8. However I needed to use Windows today and encountered a serious problem. When I logged in to Windows 8, one of my disk partiotions became empty. I cannot see any of my files neither on Windows nor Ubuntu. Used disk size shows the correct size, but there is no content in the disk. Disk partition type is NTFS and I created it when installing Ubuntu. Can I bring my files and folders back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened only one time for me. The solution was to go to Ubuntu and run `fsck` on the partition. Or open `gparted` and do a check on the partition in question.

I would first do `gparted` (You need to install it first). This way you graphically know what the problem is and if it was solved (by simply mounting the partition you should know if everything is correct when you start seeing the folders and files).

After that do an `fsck` just to make sure.

If you ran Windows 8 and it happened exactly as you mentioned, then doing it like this will solve the issue. Do not run chkdsk from Windows or try to restore something on the partition. That will create other problems if you try to repair the problem from within Ubuntu. If you already did this then install `testdisk`:

`sudo apt-get install testdisk`

And run it like `sudo testdisk` in the terminal. Follow the steps to restore a lost partition.